# Sound not working from shell script on rpi3

Tags: php, apache, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi 3 hosting a simple little local server, all this server does is display a hyperlink to activate a shell script which plays a sound.
When said button is clicked it goes to the page, but the sound is not played though the raspberry pi. How would I go about fixing this?

index.php

```
<?php
if ($_GET['run']) {
shell_exec("/var/www/html/Alarm.sh");
}
?>
<a href="?run=true">Click Me!</a>
```

Alarm.sh

```
python /home/pi/alarm.py
```

Any idea what I have done wrong?

Comment: Can you play sound from the command line? Which Raspbian O/S version is installed? Does this play as sound  `python /home/pi/alarm.py`? Show your code from alarm.py

Comment: It works perfectly fine when I ssh in and play it from the command line, I have the latest version of rasbian installed. It doesnt work at all when I try to do it from the website I set up.

Comment: edit your question and show your alarm.py code - maybe it's a path thing - hard to suggest anything else. Even if it's obvious - it's invisible to us

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way you can check to see if the alarm.py script is being run - maybe by echoing a print statement before calling python?

You may need to specify the full path to python

```
/path/to/python /home/pi/alarm.py
```

Same applies to your as-yet-unknown code in alarm.py